# Secure ajax data for submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to securely submit data to a script. After collecting the below values, I am trying to somehow, transmit the collected values, **securely**, to `process.php` however, I have never done this before.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to encrypt or somehow secure the below data and submit it with ajax.

My JQuery

```
       $('.process-button').click(function(){
            var processNum = $('.process-num').val();
            var month = $('.process-month').val();
            var amount = $('.charge-amount').val();


            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                type: "post",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);

                }
            });         
        });
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more that others can point out, but a few security concepts I can think of:

- Transmit data using HTTPS. You may need to set up your server software for this. The page you post from may also need to be in HTTPS (so that it will be the same domain)
- Do not include any information in the URL, like you often might in a GET request. (ie, POST "provider/patienthistory/patients/frankgumby/"). This is mostly handled by doing it as a POST request.
- On PHP, do not trust off the bat that the information is coming from that Javascript call. Assume someone is sending requests from a random page on your site, with made-up data, and ensure said person cannot do anything malicious.

Comment: Re: the last point, you can somewhat reduce the potential of that particular (and quite prevalent) threat by using a special hash code (token) in your payment form to guarantee your process.php script will only process POST data coming from that particular page.

Comment: @cerd : I think such tools can certainly be used to validate a session (so you're not asking for username/password on each request), but would it not be possible for a hacker to still add breakpoints in the Javascript, and change the data sent before it goes out? Assuming malice, the requesting page doesn't particularly matter.

Comment: @Katana314 - Absolutely, I would think that is one of many ways to circumvent it: A concentrated penetration attempt is obviously very hard to mitigate entirely with code. The whole point is not the particular page that is submitted, but the form object itself: Good example here: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries